# Multiple views for one model in AngularJS

Tags: model-view-controller, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS framework and my background is BackboneJS and it seems I can not figure
out conventional way to do next thing:

I have a readonly list of elements each of which has 'edit' button that switches this
particular element to an edit mode. In edit mode I need to render input elements instead
of spans, p's etc.

The way to do this in Backbone.js is simply create EditView and pass model to it, but I don't have any idea how this works in Angular.
I pass data to the scope and render the readonly list and when user clicks on 'edit' button
in the element how should I change view for the element?

Thanks!

Comment: You may check this out:  https://github.com/Wintellect/Angular-MVC-Cookbook/tree/master/CRUDOperations

Answer (score 0):

Angular makes this task simpler than Backbone by using a model for editing, then you update the original list and clear the edit model.

The view:

```
<div ng-app='App'>
<div ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    <div ng-controller='childCtrl'>
        <strong>Controller</strong>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='item in list'>{{item.name}} <button ng-click='edit($index)'>+</button></li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-show='editModel.name'>
            Name: <input type="text" ng-model='editModel.name'/> <button ng-click='save()'>Save</button><button ng-click='cancelEdit()'>Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The angular app:

```
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.list = [ {name:'item 1'}, {name:'item 2'}, {name:'item 3'} ];
}])
.controller('childCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.editModel = {};
    $scope.edit = function(index){
        $scope.editModel.index = index;
        $scope.editModel.name = $scope.list[index].name;
    };

    $scope.cancelEdit = function(){
        $scope.editModel = {};
    };

    $scope.save = function(){
        if($scope.editModel.hasOwnProperty('index')){
            $scope.list[$scope.editModel.index] = $scope.editModel;
        }
        else if($scope.editModel.name && $scope.editModel.name.length){
            $scope.list.push($scope.editModel);
        }
        $scope.cancelEdit();
    };
}]);
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guilhermenagatomo/Bp6bY/

I'm using the controller nesting so the list can be used by other controllers you have in the app, or maybe you can create a controller just to take care of the editing.